# Audio Streaming with Java Servlet in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, audio-streaming

I am trying to create a URL in my GAE Java web application that can allow streaming an audio file, but so far it only works for direct download. This is what my servlet looks like so far for downloading a file from the BlobStore with BlobKey sent in the "file_id" parameter:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) 
        throws IOException {

    BlobInfoFactory bif = new BlobInfoFactory();

    BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(req.getParameter("file_id"));
    String fileName = bif.loadBlobInfo(blobKey).getFilename();

    res.setContentType("text/plain");
    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);

    blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, res);
}
```

The servlet is mapped to a URL that looks like this:
xxx.appspot.com/fileDownload?file_id=yyy

How could I access this URL on the client side (browser or mobile application) for streaming the audio data instead of doing a direct download? 
Would I have to change the server side, the client side protocol to access it (instead of HTTP), or both?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check which audio formats are [supported by certain browsers](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp). Your best bet would be mp3 audio.
2. Use this html snippet on client side:

   `<audio controls>
     <source src="http://path/to/your/audio/file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
     Your browser does not support the audio element.
   </audio>`
3. Make sure your server serves audio files as `audio/mpeg` content type (also the content of your blob must be mp3 file):

   `res.setContentType("audio/mpeg");`
4. Remove the `Content-Disposition` header. This is used when you want browser to save a file to local disk.

Comment: Thanks Peter, worked neatly! However, what should I replace the "Content-Disposition" argument with? An empty string? I just removed the whole res.setHeader() line and it worked as well.

Comment: Exactly - just remove the whole header.